# How to read a GRIB file for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, grib

Is there some libraries for Android and iOS to read a GRIB file (General Regularly-distributed Information in Binary form) and get the weather data ?

Answer (score 2):

I just found this library for Android

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgrib/

But still looking for an iOS one if any one can help.